# Converting between windows and unix path with sed losses double slash

Tags: windows, linux, bash, path, sed

This command almost gives me what I want :-

```
echo "\\123.123.123.123\path1\1 - path2\path3 path4\path5" | sed 's_\\_/_g' | sed 's_ _\\ _g'
/123.123.123.123/path1/1\ -\ path2/path3\ path4/path5
```

But as one can see, its lost the '//' at the beginning!
ie, desired outout :-

```
//123.123.123.123/path1/1\ -\ path2/path3\ path4/path5
```

What am I missing?

---

Edit: After not testing the basics of `echo` (many thanks to all who pointed that out). I should of also been more clear on the end-game of this question.

I want to use this in a script, and define the windows path at the top.
How can I `echo` the path to a tmp file for sed?
This obviously wont work :-

```
WIN_PATH="\\123.123.123.123\path1\1 - path2\path3 path4\path5"
UNIX_PATH=`echo $WIN_PATH | sed 's_\\_/_g' | sed 's_ _\\ _g'`
```

Comment: If my eyes does not fail me, that's a backtick you are using. Use single quotes.

Comment: Ops, that was a typo in here, corrected it as my script, which works ok, but dont really like the tmp file! But doesnt matter in the long run.

Comment: why do you need a tmp file then? `SOURCE_PATH=$(echo $WIN_PATH | sed 's_\\_/_g' | sed 's_ _\\ _g')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes in `echo` - as it is the shell interprets your two backslashes as an escape sequence for `\`:

```
$ echo '\\123.123.123.123\path1\1 - path2\path3 path4\path5' | sed 's_\\_/_g' | sed 's_ _\\ _g'
//123.123.123.123/path1/1\ -\ path2/path3\ path4/path5
```

Using single quotes suppresses shell expansions (e.g. variables) and disables most escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in `\\` is already the escape secuence for `\` so you have already lost one of the `\` on the `echo`.
You can try just :

```
echo "\\123.123.123.123\path1\1 - path2\path3 path4\path5"
```

to see it.

You have to escape those `\` to make it work i.e.:

```
echo "\\\\123.123.123.123\path1\1 - path2\path3 path4\path5" | sed 's_\\_/_g' | sed 's_ _\\ _g'
//123.123.123.123/path1/1\ -\ path2/path3\ path4/path5
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash uses the \ (backslash) as an escape. It isn't being munched by sed, but by bash before passing the string to `echo`. Try:

```
echo "\\123"
```

You'll get:

```
\123
```

To solve your problem, put your text into a file, and read it from there to avoid shell escaping:

```
$ cat >file
\\123.123.123.123\path1\1 - path2\path3 path4\path5
$ cat file | sed 's_\\_/_g' | sed 's_ _\\ _g'
//123.123.123.123/path1/1\ -\ path2/path3\ path4/path5
```

Comment: Many thanks, I have updated my question, as I didnt fully describe my end-game!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do that, use single quotes so that the slash does not get interpreted.

```
echo '\\123.123.123.123\path1\1 - path2\path3 path4\path5'
```